# GNU Makefile uses the same source file for all object files

Tags: makefile, dependencies, header-files, nvcc

File structure:

```
cpp
|   Makefile
|
|   obj
|___include
|   |   a.cuh
|   |   b.cuh
|   |   c.cuh
|
|___src
|   |   a.cu
|   |   b.cu
|   |   c.cu
```

I don't have much experience with GNU make. The following was written based on different search results on Stackoverflow. The `$@` variable correctly gets the name of each object file from the list, however `$<` variable only gets the first item in the list of source file names (as per the manual, but that is what all the stack overflow answers I found are using [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964002/881459), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10639005/881459), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349717/881459)).

```
NVCC=nvcc

LIB       = lib.dll

SRC_DIR   = src
INC_DIR   = include
OBJ_DIR   = obj

CU_FILES  = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cu)

CUH_FILES = $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.cuh)

CUO_FILES = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CU_FILES:.cu=.obj)))

$(LIB): $(CUO_FILES)
    $(NVCC) --shared $^ -o $@

$(CUO_FILES): $(CU_FILES) $(CUH_FILES)
    $(NVCC) -dc $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is probably not what you want. Your rule:

```
$(CUO_FILES): $(CU_FILES) $(CUH_FILES)
    $(NVCC) -dc $< -o $@
```

means that **each object file** depends on **all source files** ad **all header files**.

What you need here is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) saying that `obj/foo.obj` depends on `src/foo.cu` and `include/foo.cuh`:

```
obj/%.obj: src/%.cu include/%.cuh
    $(NVCC) -dc $< -o $@
```

Note that you can simplify a bit the `CUO_FILES` assignment:

```
CUO_FILES = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cu,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj,$(CU_FILES))
```